# Empty intent extras in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities.

First calls second like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

returning data in second one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("a", "la-la-la");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

and trying to receive this data in first activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (currentTask != null)) {
            //Here is empty intent extas!!!

            Log.d("OrderActivity", "RESULT!!");
        }
    }
```

So, request code and response code returned, but intent extra is empty..??

Comment: what is `currentTask` and did you see your log inside `onActivityResult()`..?

Comment: A'm stupid. Everythink works fine. I have tryied to reveive information with incorrect type.

Comment: Then be polite in your words next time. don't post wrong words here :)

Comment: Thanks! Your remark helped me too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this and found the answer in the comments. To make it more discoverable for the next guy, let's restate as answer:

You must read the same data-type as you put in.

Answer (score -1):

Just call this lines before calling super.onFinish() or wherever you exit the previous activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```