# OnActivityResults to another intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, send, android-activity

I have used a switch so that when button2 is selected application allows the user to choose a image from the sd card.

On the OnActivityResult i get the image uri, i want to then get this URI filepath and use it on button 1 within the same activity with the Action_send function.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:



                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri blah = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);
                i.setType("image/*");     
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, blah);  
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "title")); // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
                break;
        }
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            //gotimage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            selectedImagePath = getPath(imageUri);
    }
}
```

}

```
private String getPath(Uri selectedImageUri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

I have seen the guys code on the other question and i seen that the guy says to use the filepath, how would this be done using the action_send function?

Many Thanks

Comment: call `SetResult(RESULT_OK,intent)`

Check this [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25196220/1587156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the file path as:

```
    public static Uri imgui;

    case R.id.button2:
        Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);  
         startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0); 
    startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent , 4);
    break;

     @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
         imgui = data.getData();  
    }  
}

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgui);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

     }  
    });
```

Comment: What i'am trying to do is pass the URI from the onactivity result to button 2 for action_send.......Both buttons are on the same class

Comment: actually i'm not clear about your question regarding action_send what this does?

Comment: I want to use the Action_send to send the image via bluetooth.

Comment: Yeah on button 1 SEND_ACTION, button 2 get image.

Comment: Right with your code it sends image but only once i take an image by the camera, i wish to get the image from sd card instead please!!

Comment: Or once i have taken an image the user can choose which compression method to use!!

Comment: imgui = intent.getData(); cannot be resolved!! tried localising variable etc but no good.

Comment: use data.getData(); sorry by mistake

Comment: I had to remove one of the startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);  as it was making me select the image twice!! But everything else is great Much appreciated fella!!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the file path from uri as

```
public void getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
       String filepath= cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

safe this value in the class level variable and then on button1 click pass the string to this method

```
public void shareThisFile(String path){

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    }
```

Comment: I get a Failure delivering result error on the onactivityresult