# What is Intent from onActivityResult Parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here is my `first activity` code from where I call the `second Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT){       
    startActivityForResult(new Intent("chap.two.Chapter2Activity2"),request_Code);          
  }    
  return false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == request_Code) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
      Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
  }
}
```

And here is a code of `chap.two.Chapter2Activity2`:

```
Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Intent data = new Intent();
     //---get the EditText view---
     EditText txt_username =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
     //---set the data to pass back---
     data.setData(Uri.parse(txt_username.getText().toString()));
     setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
     //---closes the activity---
     finish();

   }
});
```

here I see that `setResult(RESULT_OK, data)` has two arguments but
`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` has three and I want know how `onActivityResult` gets value for third parameter? How it works can anyone tell me? Why isn't this error ?

Comment: Just check this ansswer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25196220/1587156

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call Activity.startActivityForResult(), you set the `requestCode`. Later, this request code is needed by `onActivityResult()` in order to determine what Activity is sending data to it. We don't need to supply `requestCode` again on `setResult()` because the `requestCode` is carried along.

The `data` is [intent data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) returned from launched intent. We usually use this data when we set `extras` on the called intent.

Consider this example:

**CALL SECOND ACTIVITY**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_CHECK);
```

**ON SECOND ACTIVITY, SET INTENT RESULT**

```
getIntent().putExtra("TADA", "bla bla bla");
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

**BACK TO FIRST ACTIVITY, ONACTIVITYRESULT()**

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHECK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    text1.setText(data.getExtras().getString("TADA") );
}
```

There you go. You should now understand what is `Intent data` and how to set and fetch the value.

Comment: but I can't understand this part.If I send REQUEST_CODE from my main activity and and get back this REQUEST_CODE in onActivityResult() which is in my mainc activity too. What is the logic of comparison ?(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEC)

Comment: the basic idea is, onActivityResult() will catch every intent it get from returning intent. Now, to determine what intent is coming back, you use `requestCode` by comparing it with what REQUEST_CODE you already have. Sometime, one activity expect one intent coming back, some other time, more than 3.

Answer (score 5):

Third parameter is Intent, which you sent from the sub-Activity(Second Activity, which is going to finish).

If you want to perform some calculations or fetch some username/password in sub-activity and you want to send the result to the main activity, then you place the data in the intent and will return to the Main activity before finish().

After that you will check in onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) in main activity for the result with Intent parameter.

Example::
MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, subActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
} 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (data.hasExtra("username") && data.hasExtra("password")) {
      String username =  data.getExtras().getString("username");
      String password =  data.getExtras().getString("password");

    }
  }
```

subActivity::

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  // Create one data intent 
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("username", "Bla bla bla..");
  data.putExtra("password", "*****");
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  super.finish();
}
```