# Recognizing multiple intents (for onActivityResult)

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 5 intents in one activity. All of them are using the `startActivityForResult`. Because all of them are to correspond to different elements in the layout. How do I recognize which intent is the result for.

For e.g. If I have intent1, intent2, intent3 all of which are using `startActivityForResult`. After the Intent business is done. How do I now in my `onActivityResult` recognize which intent was called. The intent being called upon is the android phone contacts intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `startActivityForResult()`, you set the `requestCode`. Later, you can use this request code in`onActivityResult()` to determine the intent. see [What is Intent from onActivityResult Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790129/what-is-intent-from-onactivityresult-parameters) for more. If you see the documentation of [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), it mentions:

> **protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)**
>
> *requestCode:  The integer request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this result came from.*