# How to call onClick multiple times in the same activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-edittext, speech-to-text

UPDATED:
I am creating an app where `onClickListener` is used to convert speech to text and input the text to a `List View` field.  Likewise once entered I would like to re-trigger the speech to text option and input the new text into another `List View` field whilst still retaining all the other `List View` fields which were already filled in.

The following is part of the Java file that calls the speech to text option with the various statements I want answered.  Originally the prompts appeared exactly one after the next which is perfect but it didn't assign each text to the corrresponding edit text field. It only recorded the speech to text of the very last prompt only.  Now with some help on this thread I have updated the code to the following, where `checklv1` etc correspond to unique integers:

```
   public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i1 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "What is the current time?");
    startActivityForResult(i1, check);

    Intent i2 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i2.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i2.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Is the status Confirmed or Unconfirmed?");
    startActivityForResult(i2, checklv1);

    Intent i3 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "What is the Temp?");
    startActivityForResult(i3, checklv2);
}
```

The following part of code shows to assign the text to the `editText` field `lv1`, `lv2` and `lv3`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == checklv1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == checklv2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The code is now progressing and inputting the speech to text phrases into each of the `list view` fields.  However my only issue is that `lv3` contains the correct phrase, `lv1` also contains the correct phrase but `lv2` is a the same phrase as `lv1` when it should be the phrase corresponding to `lv2`.  Most likely there is something wrong in the check assignment.

If anyone can please help me with where I have gone wrong in the above code that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: startIntent -> onActivityResult -> startIntent -> onActivityResult -> startIntent -> onActivityResult. Don't forget to handle your saved state.

Comment: do you know where in the code I should be putting startIntent, onActivityResult @Eugen Pechanec?

Comment: C'mon you can figure it out for yourself. Don't start all speech recognition at once, only the last request will be honored, just as you verified. Instead start the first one onClick. When the result returns successfully start the second one and so on.

Comment: I'm sure I can but the only issue is I get errors if I specify multiple onClick(View v). It only allows me to do it once and I cannot specify onActivityResult within onClick...some more help and guidance will definitely help me further.

Comment: Here's how you handle different results in `onActivityResult`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18725757/2444099

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So basically I should keep the onClick method as is and adjust the onActivityResult I should specify a integer for the requestCode.  I'm really sorry if I haven't understood this correctly as I'm fairly new to all of this and things seem quite hard when it's your first time doing something new

Comment: Not entirely, yes, each request should have it's own `requestCode` so you know how to proceed in `onActivityResult`. No, the `onClick` method will start only the first request. The second request will be started from `onActivityResult` after first request finishes (matching `requestCode`). Similar for the third request.

Comment: Okay, so use onClick for the first request and define the requestCode and all other requests should be a part of the onActivityResult section, correct?

Comment: Yes, time to try it. Update your question after you do.

Comment: I'll test it out in the morning and update what's been done

Comment: Hi @Eugen Pechanec, I have updated the code with what I now currently have and think I am very close to what I wish to achieve except for one minor issue.  Can you please have a look and let me know what is going wrong.  I have tried many different variables for the check but always get a repeated phrase in the `lv2` list view

Comment: Can anyone help please..

Answer (score 2):

The `check` field you are passing to `startActivityForResult` is what you should be using to distinguish the action you are performing. Pass 3 different values here and switch on them in `onActivityResult` to determine which part of the UI you want to update.

`startActivityForResult(i2, checkLv1);`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch(requestCode) {
            case checkLv1:
                update(lv1);
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you mind clarifying which part goes in the onClick method and onActivityResult method and do I need to delete anything else originally in my code?

Comment: Are you able to kindly help with where I have gone wrong in my updated code shown above @darnmason ?